# How to "automate" Paperclip with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, paperclip, attachment

I have a client who wants to bulk-upload photo files to her existing Ruby on Rails application that I developed. I've scratched together code and scripts to unzip a zip file and rename all included files sequentially:

photo0001.png, photo0002.png etc...

However, I'm stuck on how to write a model or method to go through and assign each photo to a new instance, as paperclip defines the following:

```
class Picture
 has_attached_file :photo
```

So I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
for i in 1..5
   Picture.create(:caption => "Test", :photo => "photo/photo000#{i}.png")
   `rm photo/photo000#{i}.png`
end
```

I'm sure there's more to it than that, but that's the basic idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a rake task for uploading photos, the meat of it looks like this:

```
Dir.glob(photo_path).entries.each do |e|
  puts "Uploading #{e}"
  Picture.create!(:photo => File.open(e))
end
```

I don't know if this helps, but it should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Works fantastically, thank you! A simple oversight... Can't feed the direct path but use File.open

Comment: Indeed. That's what's going on under the covers when you upload a file (kind of).